# JQuery Help: slidetoggle() is not working properly

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery Slidetoggle functionality, but not able to use properly.
The problem I'm currently facing is my div is sliding down on the click of slide image icon, but after that suddenly data div (in which data is loading) disappears. Means sliding down is perfect but div (in which data is loading , here #divMain) is not visible after that.
I want to achieve sliding effect in my code, like [this](http://www.networksolutions.com/design-develop/design-services.jsp) has (Please see Website Design, Redesign Services slider):

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div>
     <div class="jquery_inner_mid">
            <div class="main_heading">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="features.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></a>
            </div>

            <div class="plus_sign">
                <img id="imgFeaturesEx" src="images/plus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" />
                <img id="imgFeaturesCol" src="images/minus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></div>
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div id="divMain" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jquery_inner_mid">
            <div class="main_heading">
                <img src="About.jpg" alt="" title="" /></div>
            <div class="plus_sign">
                <img id="imgTechnoEx" src="images/plus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" />
                <img id="imgTechnoCol" src="images/minus.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" /></div>
            <div class="toggle_container">
                <div id="divTechnossus" >
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JQuery:

```
    $(function() {

        $('#imgFeaturesCol').hide();
        $('#imgTechnoCol').hide();

        $('#imgFeaturesEx').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetFeatureInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
                $('#divMain').html(strInfo).slideToggle("slow");
                LoadDiv();
            });
            $('#imgFeaturesEx').hide();
            $('#imgFeaturesCol').show();
        });
        $('#imgFeaturesCol').click(function() {
            $('#divMain').html("").slideToggle("slow");
            $('#imgFeaturesCol').hide();
            $('#imgFeaturesEx').show();
        });

        $('#imgTechnoEx').click(function() {
            $.getJSON("/Visitor/GetTechnossusInfo", null, function(strInfo) {
                $('#divTechnossus').html(strInfo).slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $('#imgTechnoEx').hide();
            $('#imgTechnoCol').show();
        });
        $('#imgTechnoCol').click(function() {
            $('#divTechnossus').html("").slideToggle("slow");
            $('#imgTechnoCol').hide();
            $('#imgTechnoEx').show();
        });


    })();

    function LoadDiv() {
        $('#s4').cycle({
            speed: 200,
            timeout: 0,
            pager: '#nav'
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. The div `#divMain` needs to have the style `display: none` at the beginning. Otherwise the toggles will do the opposite of what you intend.
2. I would use `slideDown` to show and `slideUp` to hide instead of `slideToggle`. Toggling is only useful when the same call can either hide or show.
3. Calling `html("")` will immediately remove the content, before the sliding animation. Either remove this call, or make it run after the slide like this:

   ```
   $('#divMain').slideUp('slow', function() {
       $(this).html('');
   });
   ```